# How to have an AJAX call return data and display it to the page with Node.js, Mongo and Mongoose.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a basic HTML form that is sending three fields of data to node via a JQuery $AJAX POST . When it gets to the server is is being stored in **var mov = new Movie(inputDataJSON);**

It then is stored in Mongo DB perfectly.

I then want to get this information out and have it display on the page. I've been experimenting with the success method of the AJAX POST and not getting anywhere.I've done this kind of thing with MYSQL/PHP and have had it work but with node/mongo I'm kind of at a dead end. I left that area blank and simply left a comment.

**Client Stuff**

```
    $(function(){       



                    $('#select_link').click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        // These are all        
                        var movieTitle = $("#movie-title").val();
                        var movieRating = $("#rating").val();
                        var movieYear = $("#year").val();
                        console.log(movieTitle)



                        var data = {};
                        data.title = movieTitle;
                        data.rating = movieRating;
                        data.releaseYear = movieYear ;
                        data.hasCreditCookie = true;




                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: JSON.stringify(data),
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            url: '/sendJSON',                       
                            success: function(data) {
                                console.log('success');    // Not sure how to get it back out to display to the page from MongoDB


                            }
                        });

                    });             
});
```

**Server Stuff**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var port = 8080;
app.listen(port);
console.log('listening on port: ' + port);

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error);




var inputDataJSON;

db.once('open', function() {
    var movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        title: {type: String},
        rating: String,
        releaseYear: Number,
        hasCreditCookie: Boolean
    });



    var Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);




    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.post('/sendJSON', function(req, res) {
        inputDataJSONString = JSON.stringify(req.body);
        inputDataJSON = JSON.parse(inputDataJSONString);



        var mov = new Movie(inputDataJSON);
        mov.save(function(err, mov) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            console.dir(mov);
        });



    });



});


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
```

**and...HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="select_div">
        <a href="#" id="select_link">Send Movie</a>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <label>Movie Title</label> <input id="movie-title" type="text" name="title"><br>
            <label>Rating</label> <input id="rating" type="text" name="rating"><br>
            <label>Year</label> <input id="year" type="text" name="year"><br>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you using a templating engine? In express+ejs you can just res.render and return your mongoDB data.. and on your AJAX.. just try to console.log the data first and see if it returned what you expected

Comment: Do you mean like Jade? I have the dependency available but I wanted to stick to raw HTML as I didn't want to focus on learning JADE, I want to focus on learning mongoose/node/mongo .

Comment: Oh nvm my first comment, I think just return a response like res.json({something:'msg'}) and console.log(data) on your ajax success option.. im not sure if that's expressjs specific but you get the idea

Comment: imho `jade` is so simple that you write faster templates , that you can write html all `<` and `/>` , also the basics in jade will do, you don't have to use all the features.

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to figure out the answer to the question I posted at the moment. Jade is nice but its secondary